# Aligning screw head slots

Tags: screws, hinges

Looking at the hinges on my piano I can see that all the screw slots are aligned horizontally. If I was to screw a piano hinge onto anything the slots would be all over the place.

So what is the trick for getting them aligned?

Comment: Just for reference, this is known as "clocking" your screws.

Comment: Yup. For woodworkers, it's all variations of "turn the screw out and redrive". Before redriving some folks machine the underside of the screw or countersink the hinge bore a little. It's fussy work. There are lots of articles about this on the web, so feel free to self-answer if you want to make a canonical "clocking" answer.

Comment: This is often referred to as "clocking" screws. It's something that some woodworkers think is very important and others aren't concerned with. There are various tips to get the slots aligned (the main one being aligning the slots the same as you start), but aiming for clocked screws comes with some potential problems. If you try it you'll soon (almost immediately!) find that it can mean that some screws aren't fully home but they can't be turned a further 180°. It's a pickle. These days with flathead screws being so much less common any need for this has reduced considerably!

Comment: Just use Robertson or phillips so you only have to turn 25 degrees or less! Problem solved forever!

Comment: To fix the problem @Graphus mentioned, some people gently file the back of the screw head until they can be aligned.

Comment: @jdv, better still use torx and nobody can see if they're aligned or not ^_^

Comment: @Graphus counter-sink all screw-heads and patch the hole with bookmatched plugs. I'll stop now.

Comment: Are screws typically machined with the threads in the same relationship to the head?  Can you clock screws by just swapping them around until they're all close then over/under torquing them a little bit?

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 you cannot count on this, no. It depends on how the wire is fed into dies, and there are at least two main ways to cut threads, and one of these doesn't care about the head orientation at all.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232, *"Are screws typically machined with the threads in the same relationship to the head?"* that is a very good question! Re. torquing to suit, that's one of the main ways to get this to happen IRL but I find it very unsatisfying to deliberately have an under-tightened screw somewhere (not to mention it's likely sitting high). A piano hinge, as the OP originally asked about, is one of the few places this may not matter enough in practice to really be an issue, but on everything else I can think off I wouldn't want to do it.